# Unable to convert SQL to JPQL

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, jpql

I am trying to convert following Oracle SQL (which works)

```
select sum(ct.some_count) from TABLE1 mc
  inner join TABLE2 xref on mc.cnum = xref.cnum
  inner join TABLE3 ct on xref.srt = ct.srt
  inner join TABLE4 pc on pc.id = xref.id
  where mc.CARD_NO = '111' and pc.code = '222';
```

To following JPQL.

```
@Query("SELECT sum(ct.someCount) FROM Table1Entity mc " +
        "inner join TABLE2Entity xref on mc.cnum = xref.cnum " +
        "inner join TABLE3Entity ct on xref.srt = ct.srt " +
        "inner join TABLE4Entity pc on pc.id = xref.id " +
        "where mc.CARD_NO = :cardNumber and pc.code = :code")
long getTotalCount(@Param("cardNumber") String cardNumber, @Param("code") String code);
```

I am getting the following Exception.

> QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Can I please get some help on what I am doing wrong?

I am using Spring and this is my Repository for this Query.

```
@Repository(value = "someCountRepository")
public interface SomeCountRepository extends JpaRepository<Table3Entity, TableId> {
        @Query("SELECT sum(ct.someCount) FROM Table1Entity mc " +
        "inner join TABLE2Entity xref on mc.cnum = xref.cnum " +
        "inner join TABLE3Entity ct on xref.srt = ct.srt " +
        "inner join TABLE4Entity pc on pc.id = xref.id " +
        "where mc.CARD_NO = :cardNumber and pc.code = :code")
        long getTotalCount(@Param("cardNumber") String cardNumber, @Param("code") String code);
}
```

Comment: Joins in JPQL are not obtained like that. For example, `SELECT p FROM Person p INNER JOIN Address a ON p.addressId = a.id WHERE a.city='London'` is incorrect, whereas, `SELECT p FROM Person p INNER JOIN p.address a WHERE a.city='London'` is the correct way to use a JPQL join.

Comment: @manish How does the query even know what 'a' is? -> INNER JOIN p.address a

Comment: JPA works with objects. Let's say there is a `Person` entity and an `Address` entity, representing a person and an address, respectively. If a person requires an address, the `Person` entity must have a field `private Address address`. Then, a valid JPA query would look like `FROM Person p INNER JOIN p.address a`. The JPA provider knows that `p.address` is of type `Address`, therefore, it will automatically map the alias `a` to whatever table the `Address` entity is mapped to. In this sense, a JPA query does look like SQL, but it requires entities and fields instead of tables and columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("SELECT sum(ct.someCount) FROM Table1Entity mc " +
        "inner join TABLE2Entity xref on mc.cnum = xref.cnum " +
        "inner join TABLE3Entity ct on xref.srt = ct.srt " +
        "inner join TABLE4Entity pc on pc.id = xref.id " +
        "where mc.CARD_NO = :cardNumber and pc.code = :code",
        nativeQuery = true) // set native query to true
long getTotalCount(@Param("cardNumber") String cardNumber, @Param("code") String code);
```

Since you are copy the query exactly from Oracle SQL which is not JPQL, then you should declare it as native query.

References : [Spring Data JPA @Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) #2.2. Native

Comment: I was trying to convert and not use native query but guess this works too. Will give it a go.

Comment: Hi thanks. But it's not working for me. Asking for additional configurations as its native.

Comment: @kang can you elaborate more why it is not working for you in detail? Or maybe you can checkout manish comment to build a proper JPQL query.